# Psycopg: Insert filename to table while copying the file

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

My Python code copying files to PostgreSQL.

It's working this way:

```
with gzip.open(<file>, 'rb') as f:
             cursor.copy_from(f, tablename, columns=[‘data_column’])
```

But I need to insert additional values/params (along with data from file) using copy_from?
For example, I want to insert filename in a separate column, i.e. implement something like this:

```
with file.open(<file>, 'rb') as f:
             cursor.copy_from([f,  <filename>], tablename, columns=[‘data_column’,’filename’])
```

Any suggestions are appreciated!
Thank you!

p.s.

Tried couple of ways, including following

```
with gzip.open(<file>, 'rb') as f:
     for line in f:
     cursor.execute("""insert into my_table (data_section, filename) values (%s, %s, %s);""", (<file>, line))
```

But of course, this approach is too slow.

Comment: Not that I know of. Two choices.  1) You open the file and append the file name as ```filename``` column to each row and then pass the complete file to ```copy_from```. I suspect it will be quicker then the ```INSERT``` method but slower then a direct ```COPY```.   2) Do the ```COPY``` and then an ```UPDATE``` at the end that fills the ```filename``` field for all rows at one time.

Comment: You could also try using [execute_values](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html#psycopg2.extras.execute_values).